# Is 10.0.0.2 a Private IP? I want to view site on other devices

Tags: networking, ip, localhost

I am using webstorm and have my site up on:

```
http://localhost:17198/sleek/index.html
```

I want to view it on other devices. My ip is `10.0.0.2` and when I try `10.0.0.2:17198` or `10.0.0.2:17198/sleek/index.html`. I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really get nothing? or an error? @Aify 10.0.2.2 is **not** the same as `localhost,` or 127.0.0.1. Please don't post misinformation here.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for services to bind to specific interfaces.  Thus, your web server may be listening on "127.0.0.1:17198" but not "10.0.0.2:17198".  Or it may be listening but have rules that limit access.

Or there could be firewall rules that prevent access to that port on any interface other than "localhost" (aka 127.0.0.1).

You'll need to check the configuration of both your server and your system.

And yes, "10.*.*.*" is a "private" IP address.  That means that it is inaccessible from the Internet but it does not in any way limit access from other devices on the same private network.  "172.16.*.*" though "172.31.*.*" and "192.168.*.*" are also all private addresses.